# How to write multiple select statements with multiple where condition in single query?

Tags: php, sql

I am working on php with sql .I have one teachers_rating table in database I want to get ratings like how many members are give 5 rating like that only 4, like 3, like so...I used this sql query check once.

```
    SELECT COUNT( teachers_rating.rating ) AS fivestar
    FROM teachers_rating
    WHERE rating = '5' and id='23'
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT( teachers_rating.rating ) AS fourstar
    FROM teachers_rating
    WHERE rating = '4'and id='23'
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT( teachers_rating.rating ) AS threestar
    FROM teachers_rating
    WHERE rating = '3'and id='23'

like that its running but out output is
fivestar    
18
14
20

but iwant this type of structure
fivestar    fourstar threestar
18           14          20
```

If any one knows please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN t.rating =5 THEN 1 END) as five,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.rating =4 THEN 1 END) as four,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.rating =3 THEN 1 END) as three
FROM teachers_rating t
WHERE t.id = '23'
```

If you want it dynamic for all `IDs` :

```
SELECT t.id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.rating =5 THEN 1 END) as five,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.rating =4 THEN 1 END) as four,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.rating =3 THEN 1 END) as three
FROM teachers_rating t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select SUM(if(rating = '5',1,0) as fivestar,SUM(if(rating = '4',1,0) as fourstar,SUM(if(rating = '3',1,0) as threestar FROM teachers_rating where id='23'
```

Answer (score 0):

In simplest form you should be able to use:

SELECT (SELECT ...) AS fivestar, (SELECT...) AS fourstar, (SELECT...) AS threestar