# MySQL pivot multi-row table to unique row table

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have the following table of results data in MySQL. I would like to pivot this around from a row per UPN per Subject Grade to a row per UPN so the table below:

```
UPN        Collection      Subject        Grade
1          Target          English        5
1          Current         English        6
1          Target          Maths          7
1          Current         Maths          7
1          Target          Art            6
1          Current         Art            6
2          Target          English        5
2          Current         English        5
2          Target          Maths          6
2          Current         Maths          7
2          Target          History        6
2          Current         History        5
```

Should pivot around to the table below:

```
UPN    English Current    English Target    Maths Current    Maths Target    Art Current    Art Target    History Current    History Target
1      6                  5                 7                7               6              6             NULL               NULL
2      5                  5                 7                6               NULL           NULL          5                  6
```

Please note that in the second table the UPN row must become unique, so no duplicate UPN rows containing NULLs.

Also where a UPN doesn't have a student then the cell value should be NULL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/990ad/2/0)

Comment: What did you try to achieve that? Please share an sql fiddle too

Comment: I'm essentially trying to re-orientate a long list of rows of values into a broadsheet view with columns going across the top.

Comment: @1000111 Added SQL Fiddle. Hope that's more helpful.

Comment: May you will get answer from this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138468/how-to-write-multiple-select-statements-with-multiple-where-condition-in-single/39138562#39138562

Comment: @Matt in the fiddle you are supposed to show your attempts to do anything on this task! :)

Comment: @Matt you want to get output like "Should pivot around to the table below:" way ???

Comment: @krunalnerikar i'd like the top table to become the bottom table.

Comment: Ok you mean to say you want output like bottom table am i right @Matt ?

Comment: @krunalnerikar yes please.

Comment: I have shared query below if it is useful for you then accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT t1.UPN,
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Current' AND t2.`Subject` = 'English'),NULL) AS 'English Current',
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Target' AND t2.`Subject` = 'English'),NULL) AS 'English Target', 
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Current' AND t2.`Subject` = 'Maths'),NULL) AS 'Maths Current',
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Target' AND t2.`Subject` = 'Maths'),NULL) AS 'Maths Target',
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Current' AND t2.`Subject` = 'Art'),NULL) AS 'Art Current',
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Target' AND t2.`Subject` = 'Art'),NULL) AS 'Art Target',
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Current' AND t2.`Subject` = 'History'),NULL) AS 'History Current',
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(t2.Grade) FROM `results` AS t2 WHERE t2.UPN = t1.UPN AND t2.`Collection` = 'Target' AND t2.`Subject` = 'History'),NULL) AS 'History Target'
FROM `results` AS t1 GROUP BY t1.`UPN`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical pviot table problem. Please check the query given below:

```
SET @sql := '';

SELECT 
CONCAT('SELECT upn, ',
GROUP_CONCAT(t.sql_code),
' FROM results GROUP BY upn;'
) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Collection =\'', Collection ,'\' AND Subject =\'', Subject ,'\' THEN Grade END) AS \'',CONCAT(Collection,' ',Subject),'\'') AS sql_code
FROM results
GROUP BY Collection,Subject
) AS t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Matt I think this will solve your problem.

You will see in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/990ad/27)

```
SELECT tb.UPN,(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Current' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'English') AS 'English Current',(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Target' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'English') AS 'English Target', 
(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Current' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'Maths') AS 'Maths Current',
(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Target' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'Maths') AS 'Maths Target',
(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Current' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'Art') AS 'Art Current',
(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Target' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'Art') AS 'Art Target',
(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Current' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'History') AS 'History Current',
(SELECT MAX(tb1.Grade) FROM `results` AS tb1 WHERE tb1.UPN = tb.UPN AND tb1.`Collection` = 'Target' AND tb1.`Subject` = 'History') AS 'History Target'
FROM `results` AS tb GROUP BY tb.`UPN`
```